# html5 video tag .ogv video file type is not working on firefox

Tags: html, wordpress, video

I am having trouble playing the .ogv file in firefox. here's the link
http://vectisgroup.com/. I think my syntax for html5 video tag was correct because its playing oon other browsers. thanks in advance!

Comment: [Did you check the Firefox forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/891033)?

Comment: I can read your video on firefox but i think it's not well encoded because the quality is horrible compared with the mp4 on chrome.
I should say it's firefox on OSX.

Comment: Same issue as @Marc-EmmanuelRamage reports, but on a Window machine.

Comment: Please include your source code with the question.

Comment: Chrome is playing the `mp4` file by default. But when playing the `ogv` file directly in Chrome, I'm having the same issues as in Firefox. So it seems very likely to be a problem with the specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), there are only 3 video formats generally supported. They are MP4, WebM and Ogg. If possible, try converting your video to one of these formats and see if that resolves it.

Comment: `ogv` files are just fine. See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media). Also, W3schools is a very unreliable source. See [W3fools](http://w3fools.com/) :)

Comment: @Boaz: I stand corrected. I did notice Ogg Opus files only work from firefox 15 onwards.